# ZF2 Service not found db adapter

Tags: mysql, database, zend-framework2

I have a problem with my database connection. I want to create a service as the Album howto.
When I create the service, ZF2 return me an error:

Error:

```
    Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException

File:
/UNXDEVCKT01/www/firewall/ZendFramework/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:496
Message:
Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for user-table
Stack trace:
#0 /UNXDEVCKT01/www/firewall/ZendFramework/module/Firewall/src/Firewall/Controller/ServiceController.php(28): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('user-table')
#1 /UNXDEVCKT01/www/firewall/ZendFramework/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractActionController.php(83): Firewall\Controller\ServiceController->addAction()
#2 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#3 /UNXDEVCKT01/www/firewall/ZendFramework/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#4 /UNXDEVCKT01/www/firewall/ZendFramework/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#5 /UNXDEVCKT01/www/firewall/ZendFramework/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractController.php(117): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#6 /UNXDEVCKT01/www/firewall/ZendFramework/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/Mvc/DispatchListener.php(114): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#7 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#8 /UNXDEVCKT01/www/firewall/ZendFramework/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#9 /UNXDEVCKT01/www/firewall/ZendFramework/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#10 /UNXDEVCKT01/www/firewall/ZendFramework/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/Mvc/Application.php(309): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#11 /UNXDEVCKT01/www/firewall/ZendFramework/public/index.php(17): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#12 {main}
```

/module/Firewall/Module.php

```
namespace Firewall;

use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener,
    Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent,
    Firewall\Model\UserTable;

class Module
{
    // ...
    public function getServiceConfiguration()
    {
        return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'user-table' => function($sm) {
                $dbAdapter = $sm->get('db-adapter');
                $table = new UserTable($dbAdapter);
                return $table;
            },
        ),
        );
    }
}
```

/module/Application/Module.php

```
namespace Application;

use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter as DbAdapter;

class Module
{
    public function getServiceConfiguration()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'db-adapter' => function($sm) {
                    $config = $sm->get('config');
                    $config = $config['db'];
                    $dbAdapter = new DbAdapter($config);
                    return $dbAdapter;
                },
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

/module/Application/config/autoload/global.php

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'driver' => 'Pdo',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:dbname=firewall;hostname=localhost',
        'username' => 'aaaaaa',
        'password' => 'aaaaaa',
        'driver_options' => array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
        ),
    ),
);
```

my call in a controller:

```
if (!$this->userTable) {
            $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
            $this->userTable = $sm->get('user-table');
        }
        return $this->userTable;
```

Thanks you very very much for your helping... I'm blocked.. :/

Comment: probably, /UNXDEVCKT01/www/firewall/ZendFramework/config/autoload/firewall.local.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use :

```
public function getServiceConfig() //instead of getServiceConfiguration()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you trying to use service to to configure your Db environment in global.php  but the way you wrote  your code is not using service manager in global.php.

Try to change your global to this since you are using service manager and factory db.

```
 return array(
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
    ),
),
    'db' => array('driver' => 'Pdo',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:dbname=firewall;host=localhost;charset=utf8',
    'user' => 'root', 'pass' => 'aaaa' ),
     'driver_options' => array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''       
),
```

);